# Pass a string number and redirect with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to create the redirect from one domain to another and pass string (only numbers) with that domain, so basically:

```
domain1.com/aaa/11111 -> domain2.com/aaa.php?aaa=11111

domain1.com/aaa/22336 -> domain2.com/aaa.php?aaa=22336
```

etc.

What I have is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(/aaa/[0-9]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(aaa/[0-9]+)/?$ http://domain2.com/aaa.php?%1 [R=301,L]
```

It's redirecting properly, but the result is `http://domain2.com/aaa.php?/aaa/12224`, how to make it `http://domain2.com/aaa.php?aaa=12224` ?

Comment: The `%1` refers to the parts captured using `()`. Just place those `()` differently…

Comment: @deceze thanks man, I appreciate your guidance. It's working as expected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this, you don't actually need that condition, since the pattern inside the rule itself already takes care of mathing that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?aaa/(\d+)/?$ http://domain2.com/aaa.php?aaa=$1 [R=301]
```